# Como unir los valores de un objeto de un json a un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Tengo este JSON.

[image: Json]

```
[{
    GRUPO1: '3096',
    PER1: '0',
    PER2: '0',
    PER3: '0',
    PER4: '0',
    PER5: '0',
    PER6: '0',
    PER7: '3096',
    PER8: '0',
    PER9: '0',
    PER10: '0',
    PER11: '0',
    PER12: '0',
    TOTAL: '3096'
}]
```

Lo que necesito es unir todos los valores de los objetos del JSON en un arreglo, de modo que quede así:

```
var json_devuelto = [];
json_devuelto = ['3096''0','0','0','0','0','0','3096','0','0','0','0','0','3096'];
```

Comment: Hola Jean Paul, será mucho mejor si en lugar de pegar una imagen copias el código. Muchos de nosotros no tenemos acceso al servidor de imágenes con texto no hay problemas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer directamente con javascript, usando los métodos [keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) y [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
// en tu caso entrada sería tbla_altas[0]
var entrada = {"a":"10","b":"11","c":"12"};

var resultado = Object.keys(entrada).map(function(k) { return entrada[k] });

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias! :)!

Answer (score 3):

También existe la propiedad [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) que devuelve directamente los valores de las "keys" :

```js
var entrada = {"a":"10","b":"11","c":"12"};

var resultado = Object.values(entrada);

console.log(resultado);
```

Cierto lo que comenta Mariano en los comentarios, de hecho, la documentación aportada sugiere varios Polyfills :

[Object#values y Object#entries del propio spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries)

[Object#values y Object#entries propuesto anteriormente](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js)

Comment: Es experimental y muchos navegadores no lo implementaron.

Comment: Cierto, pero puedes usarlos usando algún polyfill como los que sugiere la documentación, o algún transpilador como babel.